# hide a node from node author in view

Tags: views

I have a view of content type 'video' which shows a preview videos of particular author. I have passed content id as contextual filter. Now,I want to show a node (video) to the other users but not the node author.How can I hide it from only the node author in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Code:

To adjust views to show/hide author content...

- under Advanced Tab create a Relationship, Content:Author, Require this field
- create a new Filter, User:Current, Relationship Author(or whatever name you gave the relationship), Is the logged in user -> No

This will compare the author of the content to the currently logged in user and only show the content if they don't match. This method can be used to show only content by the current user by changing the 'Is the logged in user' -> Yes